# Probability distribution whose moments are 2n choose n

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, catalan-numbers

The probability distribution whose odd moments are zero and whose even moments are the catalan numbers is the semicircle distribution.

What is the distribution whose even moments are n choose n/2? Is there a good way of recovering a distribution from its moments?

Comment: Do you know about MGF?